# map and unordered_map containing pointers to double?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, reference, unordered-map

If I have a std::map and std::unordered_map how could I use pointers on the double so that when the unordered_map updates the double value for a particular key, this is already reflected in the std::map for the same "key"?

So:

unordered_map["1"] = 6 causes map["1"] to be 6 also....

Comment: You might like to accept a solution if one of them was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason why you can't use pointers.

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<double>> umap;
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<double>> omap;

    std::shared_ptr<double> value(new double(1234.5));

    umap.emplace("key", value);
    omap.emplace("key", value);

    std::cout << "umap " << *umap["key"] << "\n";
    std::cout << "omap " << *omap["key"] << "\n";

    *umap["key"] = 9999.1;
    std::cout << "omap " << *omap["key"] << "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
umap 1234.5
omap 1234.5
omap 9999.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, double> um;
std::unordered_map<std::string, double*> om;

om["1"] = &um["1"];
```

From now on, `*om["1"]` is always the value of the corresponding element in `um`. Just make sure you never delete elements from the unordered map.

(Source: [iterator and reference invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6442829/596781))

Comment: Even rehashing will invalidate iterators and references won't it? Not just erasure.

Comment: @Troy: rehashing invalidates iterators but not references. (Because it doesn't move the data around, but it changes the iteration order.)

Comment: @Troy: 23.2.5p9 "Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements."